# MySql SELECT command denied to user (Despite having all privileges)

Tags: mysql, privileges

Really lost on this one.  Apparently this error text can be a red herring.  Hoping to get some other eyes on this.  I'm doing this as a user with specified privileges.  When I try the commands as root, everything works just fine, so I've narrowed it down to permissions or an issue w/ the user.

Basically, I'm calling DELETE on a row.  Pretty simple stuff.

```
DELETE FROM hits WHERE id IN(12345) AND userId = 1
```

That results in this error:

```
{ [Error: ER_COLUMNACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: SELECT command denied to user 'auctions'@'myhost' for column 'id' in table 'hits']
```

Okay, weird... I know the user has privileges.  The following query returns a set of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM hits
```

At first the user had SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE.  Now I've just done GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES (from any host) but I get the same results.  Here's what SHOW GRANTS shows

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database`.`hits` TO 'auctions'@'%'
```

Yet, I still get this same error.  As per before, running as root everything works just fine.

This is a node script calling the queries, but I've confirmed the behavior through PhpMyAdmin as well, so I will assume that's not to blame.

My version is 5.6.19

Comment: Try issuing a `flush privileges` statement and re-try the delete afterwards.

Comment: Sorry didn't include that -- did it loads of times.